# Django ORM multiple inner join in query

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I want to be able to do queries involving multiple inner joins using Django ORM, here's my model (showing only relevant fields)

```
class Students(models.Model):

    class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
        preRegistered = 0 #No ha aceptado terminos y condiciones
        Enabled = 1
        Disabled = 2
        Suspended = 3
        Test = 4
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    trainingPath = models.ForeignKey(trainingPaths, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status.choices, default=0)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modificationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'Students'

class trainingPaths(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, null=False)
    shortName = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modificationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'Training_Path'

class Courses(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, null=False)
    path = models.URLField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    shortName = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=True)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modificationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    course_image = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'Courses'

class CoursesXTrainingP(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    trainingPath = models.ForeignKey(trainingPaths, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Courses, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    alternativeName = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modificationDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta():
        db_table = 'Courses_X_Training_Paths'
```

I want to get the information of the courses that a student has according to the value of the "trainingPath".

this is my SQL query

```
select 
    courses.id, courses.`name`, courses.course_image 
from 
    students 
join 
    courses_x_training_paths 
on 
    students.trainingPath_id = courses_x_training_paths.trainingPath_id 
join 
    courses 
on 
    courses_x_training_paths.course_id = courses.id 
where 
    students.trainingPath_id=1;
```

I have tried several ways and none of them have worked, could you please help me?

Comment: If you have a student for example: `s = Student.objects.first()` then you can do something like: `Courses.objects.only('pk', 'name', 'course_image').filter(coursesxtrainingp_set__trainingPath=s.training_path)`

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with:

```
Courses.objects.filter(
    coursesxtrainingp__trainingPath_id=1
)
```

The join on the `Students` model is not necessary, since we already know that the `trainingPath_id` is one by filtering on the `CoursesXTrainingP` model.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Student` instead of <s>`Students`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `modification_date` instead of <s>`modificationDate`</s>.